# Multiple URLs, one website in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, ssl

I have a bug on my production website.. people come in from one domain, a cookie gets set, but later (on checkout), the code redirects to the primary URL behind SSL where the cookie gets lost. I have a strategy to fix (URL string) but I need to set-up my development machine so that it is using 2 URLs to recreate the conditions to verify.

Does anyone have an idea of how I might be able to configure both Casini and IIS express to load my project, or multiple URLs with IIS express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assing multiple URL to your aplication modifying the applicationhost.config file inside IISExpress\config. You must be carefull, use the configuration file that IIS is using (Because Visual Studio might be using a different config file for the IIS, mine it's in user/documents).
Once you locate the file, go to the < sites> section and locate your application. Then go to < bindings> section and add all the urls you want.
Hope this work for you.